# facebook registration and authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

i'm using the registration plugin for my website

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration

i want permission to post users's wall is there any way that on the same log in 
( on the registration ) the user will promp to agree for the permissions (authentication)?

thanks !

Comment: are you using facebook-c#-sdk ? you just want the application to ask for post permission even you have logged in already?

Comment: Is this part of a web application or a desktop/phone based app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Facebook Developer Forum](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=309008):

> There is no way at the moment to requests extended permissions through
>   the Registration Plugin so you'll need to request it afterwards.

It goes on to acknowledge that this is a missing feature that should be added at some point.

From what I can find, it looks like the legacy [fb:prompt-permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/prompt-permission/) tag would be a great way to ask the user to grant the permission. However, Facebook is [in the process of deprecating FBML](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/), so that's probably not a good idea.

The [Facebook Authentication documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) explains how to gain the additional permissions using the latest OAuth model.  I am still struggling to wrap my head around this myself.

Comment: The [Javascript SDK docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.login/) show how to use a Javascript call to request the additional permissions.  This looks analogous to the deprecated fb:prompt-permission FBML tag.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Facebook registration I'm assuming you have a database that collects user info. So what you need to do is not rely on Facebook to see which user has registered with your website but instead use the simple login with permissions on first time users and then after they are "connected" to your website check to see if they are in your database or not, if not send them to the Facebook registration plugin page and force them to register. :)